# How can I use Function as value in dictionary? (C#)

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-4.0, initialization, fill

I want to create a dictionary and fill it in a specific way.

```
public struct Position
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public char Orientation { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<Position, Position> ChangePosition;
```

the Orientation can be 'N','S','E','W' means North, South ,...

when the first key is **X,Y,'N'** ---> the value should be **X, Y+1 , 'N'**

So the dictionary can predicate next position of the item based on current position and direction of moving.

How can I fill this dictionary?
Or is there any other better way of implementing it?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I found this solution, however I guess maybe something like `Action<>` can make it better:

```
ChangePosition= new Dictionary<char, Func<Position, Position>>
{
    {'N', pos => new Position {X = pos.X, Y = pos.Y + 1, Orientation = pos.Orientation}},
    {'E', pos => new Position {X = pos.X+1, Y = pos.Y , Orientation = pos.Orientation}},
    {'W', pos => new Position {X = pos.X-1, Y = pos.Y, Orientation = pos.Orientation}},
    {'S', pos => new Position {X = pos.X, Y = pos.Y - 1, Orientation = pos.Orientation}},
};
```

Comment: The algorithm here is both trivial and cheap.  Why choose a look-up solution?

Comment: @J... whats your suggestion please?

Comment: Filling out 4 values in a dictionary should not be *too* hard... What exactly you are trying to simplify in those 4 lines?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes , there are 4 now, but I try to use some kind of function in dictionary. just my preference and curiosity. and also I dont catch how to add 4 dynamic values to dictionary. I mean the value should be based on the key.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are looking for. Sample code that you trying to achieve (even if not compilable) could help someone to answer that.

Comment: Change Orientation into an enum and switch on the values. Are you supposed to pass in an initial value to your method? How do you determine the first value of the Dictionary that's returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend making Position an object and the compass direction characters ('N', 'E', 'W', 'S') enums. The resulting interface is much cleaner, and more intuitive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DictionaryOfFunctions_StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Position start = new Position()
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                Orientation = CompassDirection.North
            };
            start.Move(CompassDirection.North, 5);
            start.Print(); // X: 0 Y: 5 Orientation: North
            start.Move(CompassDirection.SouthWest, 5);
            start.Print(); // X: -5 Y: 0 Orientation: SouthWest
            start.Move(CompassDirection.East);
            start.Print(); // X: -5 Y: 0 Orientation: East
            start.Move(dX: 5, dY: 1, newDirection: CompassDirection.West);
            start.Print(); // X: 0 Y: 1 Orientation: West
            start.Move(dY: -1, newDirection: CompassDirection.North);
            start.Print(); // X: 0 Y: 0 Orientation: North
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public enum CompassDirection
    {
        NorthWest,
        North,
        NorthEast,
        East,
        SouthEast,
        South,
        SouthWest,
        West
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public CompassDirection Orientation { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public void Move(int dX = 0, int dY = 0, CompassDirection? newDirection = null)
        {
            X += dX;
            Y += dY;
            Orientation = newDirection.HasValue ? newDirection.Value : Orientation;
        }

        public void Move(CompassDirection newDirection, int distance = 0)
        {
            var movement = new Dictionary<CompassDirection, Action>
            {
                {CompassDirection.NorthWest, () => Move(dY: 1, dX: -1)},
                {CompassDirection.North, () => Move(dY: 1)},
                {CompassDirection.NorthEast, () => Move(dY: 1, dX: 1)},
                {CompassDirection.East, () => Move(dX: 1)},
                {CompassDirection.SouthEast, () => Move(dY: -1, dX: 1)},
                {CompassDirection.South, () => Move(dY: -1)},
                {CompassDirection.SouthWest, () => Move(dY: -1, dX: -1)},
                {CompassDirection.West, () => Move(dX: -1)}
            };
            Orientation = newDirection;
            for (int i=0; i< distance; i++)
            {
                Action changePosition = movement[Orientation];
                changePosition();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void Print(this Position pos)
        {
            string display = $"X: {pos.X} Y: {pos.Y} Orientation: {pos.Orientation}";
            Console.WriteLine(display);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be one solution . Thank you